# How do I get a hash from an array based on a value in the hash?

Tags: ruby

How do I grab a hash from an array based on a value in the hash? In this case I want to select the hash that has the lowest score, being `potato`. I use Ruby 1.9.

```
[
  { name: "tomato", score: 9 },
  { name: "potato", score: 3 },
  { name: "carrot", score: 6 }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Enumerable's `min_by` method:

```
ary.min_by {|h| h[:score] } 
#=> { name: "potato", score: "3" }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your intention is to compare by the number rather than as strings.

```
array.min_by{|h| h[:score].to_i}
```

**Edit** Since the OP changed the question, the answer becomes

```
array.min_by{|h| h[:score]}
```

which now makes no difference from Zach Kemp's answer.

Comment: I just edited my question. I'm assuming this means `to_i` is redundant.

Comment: `to_i` is **now** redundant because you **changed** your question perhaps after looking at my answer. Before, it was not.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's [`Enumerable#min_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) is definitely the way to go; however, just for kicks, here is a solution based on [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce):

```ruby
array.reduce({}) do |memo, x|
  min_score = memo[:score]
  (!min_score || (min_score > x[:score])) ? x : memo
end
```

Comment: But `min_by` works on my Ruby, which is 1.9.x. Am I missing something? +1 for alternative solution, though!

Comment: `min_by` is a 1.9 method as well.

Comment: Err, ya, looks like it goes all the way back to 1.8.7.  Just posting for variety, I guess! =)