# how do I search for a string value inside an array stored in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash, enumerator

I am using ruby on rails and trying to figure out if I can (and/or how I) search for a Hash within an Array for a specific string value?  If there is a match (finds Bob), I want it to return True.

```

```
string_query = "Bob@gmail.com"
```

```
email_array is the following:                                                                                                                       
[
    [0] {
        "email" => "bill@gmail.com",
         "name" => "william"
    },
    [1] {
        "email" => "mike@gmail.com",
         "name" => "michael"
    },
    [2] {
        "email" => "Bob@gmail.com",
         "name" => "robert"
    }
]
```

```

I see this example on Stack Overflow - but it is numeric.  Mine is a string.
[How do I get a hash from an array based on a value in the hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553749/how-do-i-get-a-hash-from-an-array-based-on-a-value-in-the-hash)

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want to return `true` if, given an array of hashes and a string `s`, at least one element of the array (a hash) has a key or value that is a string that constains `s` as a substring? I suggest you edit your question to clarify, rather than try to explain in a comment, as questions are expected to be clear and complete. One small thing: some readers may want to cut and past your code. To do so they must then remove `[0]`, `[1]` and `[2]`. You should remove such extraneous bits before posting.

Comment: Also, please assign a variable to your array (e.g., `arr = [{ "email"=>...` so that readers can refer to that variable without having to define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this as I am out now, but this could work

```
string_query = "Bob@gmail.com"
email_array.each do |s|
   if s['email'] == string_query
       #your comparision statements here 
   end
end
```

Comment: great - thanks.  for the solution to work, I had to use ["email"] ... double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
string_query = "Bob@gmail.com"


email_array = [{
        "email" => "bill@gmail.com",
         "name" => "william"
    },
    {
        "email" => "mike@gmail.com",
         "name" => "michael"
    },
    {
        "email" => "Bob@gmail.com",
         "name" => "robert"
    },
    {
        "email" => "Bob@gmail.com",
         "name" => "robert2"
    }
]
```

If you want to select all of the matching hashes you can use `select`

```
email_array.select {|hash| hash["email"] == string_query }

#=> [{"email"=>"Bob@gmail.com", "name"=>"robert"}, {"email"=>"Bob@gmail.com", "name"=>"robert2"}]
```

If you simply want to check for `true` or `false`, use `any?`

```
email_array.any? {|hash| hash["email"] == string_query }

#=> true
```

If you are only interested in the first instance. You can use `detect`

```
email_array.detect {|hash| hash["email"] == string_query }

#=> {"email"=>"Bob@gmail.com", "name"=>"robert"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
email_array.select {|hash| hash["email"] == string_query }.present?
```